# Performance impact of view on aggregate function vs result set limiting

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-performance

### The problem

Using **PostgreSQL 13**, I ran into a performance issue selecting the highest id from a view that joins two tables, depending on the select statement I execute.

Here's a sample setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  joincol VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE test2 (
  joincol VARCHAR
);

CREATE INDEX ON test1 (id);
CREATE INDEX ON test1 (joincol);
CREATE INDEX ON test2 (joincol);

CREATE VIEW testview AS (
SELECT test1.id,
       test1.joincol AS t1charcol,
       test2.joincol AS t2charcol
FROM   test1, test2
WHERE  test1.joincol = test2.joincol
);
```

### What I found out

I'm executing two statements which result in completely different execution plans and runtimes. The following statement executes in less than 100ms. As far as I understand the execution plan, the runtime is independent of the rowcount, since Postgres iterates the rows one by one (starting at the highest id, using the index) until a join on a row is possible and immediately returns.

```
SELECT id FROM testview ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

However, this one takes over 1 second on average (depending on rowcount), since the two tables are "joined completely", before Postgres uses the index to select the highest id.

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM testview;
```

Please refer to this sample on dbfiddle to check the explain plans:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bkMNeY6zXqBAYUsprJ5eWZ/1

#### My real environment

On my real environment `test1` contains only a hand full of rows (< 100), having unique values in `joincol`. `test2` contains up to ~10M rows, where `joincol` always matches a value of `test1`'s `joincol`. `test2`'s `joincol` is not nullable.

#### The actual question

Why does Postgres not recognize that it could use an *Index Scan Backward* on row basis for the second select? Is there anything I could improve on the tables/indexes?

Comment: As a side note: the parentheses around the SELECT in the CREATE VIEW statement are totally useless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the hint. I like to use this style since my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) applies some better color schema making it easier to read.

Comment: Then IntelliJ has a really strange assumption on how SQL should look like. Does it apply a different coloring for "stand-alone" queries in parentheses as well? e.g.: `(select 42);` vs `select 42;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nope. The coloring basically only "separates". When I'm inside of the paranthesis with my cursor, "everything else" of the query is slightly blurred

Comment: An answer to your question "why postgres does it like that" is: because this is how its optimizer is coded. Optimizer is not perfect and doesn't recognize and/or perform some transformations that it could.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov well then that was some really wasted 50 reputation...

Comment: Please start any performance question by disclosing your version of Postgres. Cardinalities are also essential (number of rows, number of distinct values in key columns).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I edited the question and added the information.

Comment: Still unclear. `table2 contains up to ~10M values,` A table contains *rows*, not *values*. `where joincol should always match a value of table1's joincol` Should? That would be less than 100 distinct values in `table2.joincol`? (And the whole query would be pointless.) Seems like a mix between describing your setup and the objective of the query. How many distinct values are there in `table2.joincol`?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter `table2.joincol`'s joincol always matches a row in `table1.joincol`. The amount of distinct values in `table2.joincol` is less than 100 since `table1` has less than 100 rows (`unique table1.joincol, not nullable`).

This view is basically made to join these two tables without the user having to know about them. The user of this view just wants to fetch the highest id returned by the view.

Comment: We speak of `table1` and `table2`, but the test case in the question uses `test`and `test2`. It would be helpful to consolidate all this information and the names in the question to avoid confusion. Sounds like a standard one-to-many relationship. There should be a `UNIQUE` constraint and a FK constraint? Please consolidate your question. I have a couple of things to put in an answer, but please be clear first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Queries not strictly equivalent

> why does Postgres not recognize that it could use a Index Scan Backward on row basis for the second select?

To make the context clear:

- `max(id)` excludes `NULL` values. But `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` does not.
- `NULL` values sort last in ascending sort order, and first in descending. So an `Index Scan Backward` might not find the greatest value (according to `max()`) first, but any number of `NULL` values.

The formal equivalent of:

```
SELECT max(id) FROM testview;
```

is not:

```
SELECT id FROM testview ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

but:

```
SELECT id FROM testview ORDER BY id DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1;
```

The latter query doesn't get the fast query plan. But it would with an index with matching sort order: `(id DESC NULLS LAST)`.

That's different for the aggregate functions `min()` and `max()`. Those get a fast plan when targeting table `test1` directly using the plain PK index on `(id)`. But not when based on the view (or the underlying join-query directly - the view is not the blocker). An index sorting NULL values in the right place has hardly any effect.

***We*** know that `id` in this query can never be `NULL`. The column is defined `NOT NULL`. And the join in the view is effectively an `INNER JOIN` which cannot introduce `NULL` values for `id`.
***We*** also know that the index on `test.id` cannot contain NULL values.
But the Postgres query planner is not an AI. (Nor does it try to be, that could get out of hands quickly.) I see **two shortcomings**:

- `min()` and `max()` get the fast plan only when targeting the table, regardless of index sort order, an index condition is added: `Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)`
- `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` gets the fast plan only with the exactly matching index sort order.

Not sure, whether that might be improved (easily).

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8748792e7a4947dfc10c56d564f7c3ad)* - demonstrating all of the above

#### Indexes

> Is there anything I could improve on the tables/indexes?

This index is completely useless:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "test" ("id");
```

The PK on `test.id` is implemented with a unique index on the column, that already covers everything the additional index might do for you.

There may be more, waiting for the question to clear up.

#### Distorted test case

The test case is too far away from actual use case to be meaningful.

In the test setup, each table has 100k rows, there is no guarantee that every value in `joincol` has a match on the other side, and both columns can be NULL

Your real case has 10M rows in `table1` and < 100 rows in `table2`, every value in `table1.joincol` has a match in `table2.joincol`, both are defined `NOT NULL`, and `table2.joincol` is unique. A classical one-to-many relationship. There should be a `UNIQUE` constraint on `table2.joincol` and a FK constraint `t1.joincol --> t2.joincol`.

But that's currently all twisted in the question. Standing by till that's cleaned up.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explaination and especially the elaboration on `NULLS LAST` to match the `max` function. I gave some more queries a go on my "real" data - however it seems that the optimizer just isn't "smart" enough to figure the better query plan.

Comment: Thank you Erwin!  Interesting, that index doesn't store NULL (If I know well). So if optimizer use just indexes, the optimizer must know, there isn't NULL in that column.  I can create index like this: CREATE INDEX ON test (joincol, id DESC NULLS LAST);  And no influence?  There is an Aggregate row on the top of the plan. That we can't eliminate, can? It is about 8% cost.

Comment: @LászlóTóth: `Interesting, that index doesn't store NULL (If I know well).` Not sure I understand. Indexes do store NULL values. But the index in question is on the `PRIMARY KEY` column, which cannot be NULL by definition.

Comment: I believed that bad. Sorry. Yes postgres index store null-s, I can specify first or last! :) CREATE INDEX ON test (joincol, id DESC NULLS LAST); Why doesn't influence the plan?

Comment: @LászlóTóth: An index with `id DESC NULLS LAST` as first or only expression *does* influence the query plan for `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`. See the updated explanation and the fiddle to go with it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8748792e7a4947dfc10c56d564f7c3ad

Answer (score -1):

This is a very good problem, and good testcase.
I tested it in postgres 9.3 perhaps 13 is can it more more fast.

I used Occam's Razor and i excluded some possiblities

- View  (without view is slow to)
- JOIN can filter some rows (unfortunatly in your test not, but more length md5 5-6 yes)
- Other basic equivalent select statements not solve yout problem (inner query or exists)
- I achieved to use just index, but because the tables isn't bigger than indexes it was not the solution.

I think

```
CREATE INDEX on "test" ("id");
```

is useless, because PK!

If you change this

```
CREATE INDEX on "test" ("joincol");
```

to this

```
CREATE INDEX ON TEST (joincol, id);
```

Than the second query use just indexes.

After you run this

```
REINDEX table test;
REINDEX table test2;
VACUUM ANALYZE test;
VACUUM ANALYZE test2;
```

you can achive some performance tuning. Because you created indexes before inserts.

I think the reason is the two aim of DB.

First aim optimalize just some row. So run Nested Loop. You can force it with limit x.
Second aim optimalize whole table. Run this query fast for whole table.

In this situation postgres optimalizer didn't notice that simple MAX can run with NESTED LOOP. Or perhaps postgres cannot use limit in aggregate clause (can run on whole partial select, what is filtered with query).

And this is very expensive. But you have possiblities to write there other aggregates, like SUM, MIN, AVG stb.

Perhaps can help you the Window functions too.