# Getting top 3 rows for each ID in a list

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have this SQL query to get related comments for each ID in a list:

```sql
SELECT comments.id, comments.body, comments.created_at
     , comments.like_count, comments.post_id
FROM   comments
WHERE  comments.is_active AND comments.is_show 
AND    comments.post_id in (1, 7, 9, 11, 3)
GROUP BY comments.id
ORDER BY comments.id
LIMIT 3   <----- this is not working correctly!
```

I want to get the top 3 comments for each post id in the given list (1, 7, 9, 11, 3).
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will nuke the performance of solutions suggested so far:

```sql
SELECT c.*
FROM   unnest('{1, 7, 9, 11, 3}'::int[]) AS p(post_id)  -- assuming integer?
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT id, body, created_at, like_count, post_id
   FROM   comments c
   WHERE  is_active
   AND    is_show 
   AND    c.post_id = p.post_id
   ORDER  BY like_count DESC NULLS LAST  -- assuming this defines "top"?
   LIMIT  3
   ) c
ORDER  BY id, like_count DESC NULLS LAST;  -- see below
```

Needs an index on `(post_id, like_count)` to be **fast**.

Unlike slow solutions with `row_number()`, which have to scan the whole comments table, this can identify the top 3 comments per  `post_id` from the index cheaply. For big tables, this is faster by orders of magnitude.

See:

- [Limit number of rows per group from join (NOT to 1 row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768144/limit-number-of-rows-per-group-from-join-not-to-1-row/30768557#30768557)
- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

If `like_count` is defined `NOT NULL` (as it probably should), you can simplify to `ORDER  BY id, like_count DESC`. Else you need `DESC NULLS LAST`, and the optimal index is on `(post_id, like_count DESC NULLS LAST)`. About that:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)
- [Performance impact of view on aggregate function vs result set limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68665508/performance-impact-of-view-on-aggregate-function-vs-result-set-limiting/69155660#69155660)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [row_number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html). Something like:

```
SELECT c.id, c.body, c.created_at, c.like_count, c.post_id
FROM (
 SELECT comments.*, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY post_id ORDER BY id) rn
 FROM comments
 WHERE comments.is_active AND comments.is_show 
  AND  comments.post_id in (1, 7, 9, 11, 3)
) c
WHERE rn <= 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ROW_NUMBER to get 3 comments for every postid

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT comments.id, comments.body, comments.created_at
       , comments.like_count, comments.post_id
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY post_id  ORDER BY id) rn
 FROM comments
 WHERE comments.is_active AND comments.is_show 
       AND  comments.post_id in (1, 7, 9, 11, 3)
)
SELECT id, body, created_at, like_count, post_id
FROM CTE WHERE rn < 4
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: your answer is great,
thank you for teaching me to use CTE and ROW_NUMBER. please replace the dot from .ROW_NUMBER() to ,. thank you so much

Comment: yeah but you can always edit typos